# VS 2008 complains about a property code not generated because the subjacent type is not marked Seializable

Tags: c#, winforms

Annoying error (first time I see it) "Code generation for property 'SourceFieldList' failed. Error was: Type 'KeyboardEnabledControls.SortFieldDescriptor' in Assembly ... is not marked as serializable."

The code for that property follows

```
protected List<SortFieldDescriptor> sourceFieldsList;

    public List<SortFieldDescriptor> SourceFieldList
    {
        get 
        {
            if (DesignMode) {
                sourceFieldsList = new List<SortFieldDescriptor>();
             }

            return sourceFieldsList; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (DesignMode)
                return;

            sourceFieldsList = value;
        }
    }
```

The class (it's a user control) has another property tailored as much as the one rejected, which don't causes trouble

```
    protected List<SortFieldDescriptor> destinationFieldsList;

    public List<SortFieldDescriptor> DestinationFieldList
    {
        get
        {
            if (DesignMode) {
                destinationFieldsList = new List<SortFieldDescriptor>();
                return destinationFieldsList;
            }

            destinationFieldsList.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < destinationList.Items.Count; i++) {
                SortFieldDescriptor sd = (SortFieldDescriptor)destinationList.Items[i];
                sd.EnableControlBreak = destinationList.GetItemChecked( i );
            }
            return destinationFieldsList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (DesignMode)
                return;

            destinationFieldsList = value;
        }
    }
```

Finally, the "culprit" class

```
[Serializable()]
public class SortFieldDescriptor
{
    public string Abrev { get; protected set; }                           
    public string FullName { get; protected set; } // the logical name of field
    public string ComboDisplay { get { return String.Format( "{0} ({1})", FullName, Abrev ); } }      

    public string PropertyName { get; protected set; }

    public bool EnableControlBreak { get; set; }

    public SortFieldDescriptor( string abr, string fname, string pname )
    {
        Abrev = abr;
        FullName = fname;
        PropertyName = pname;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ComboDisplay;
    }

}
```

aS YOU can see, I marked the type as Serializable() (even if I dont want to serialize it) at no avail: the error persists.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried implementing `ISerializable`?

Comment: try cleaning solution...or try adding this attribute just for peace of mind [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]

Comment: Sorry: just after I asked the question, I found a very close one. The solution is to mark the public properties I don't want to set in the desined as [Browsable(false)] and as suggested terrybozzio. What ia annoying is that this user control is near symmetrical to another one which have not the analgous proerty hidden from the designer, its underlying type not marked as serializable, and it worked ok from seven days to date. MS keeps giving up lots of surprises. May be to no get bored...